# Linking record created in trigger to the trigger source

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have two tables, `contact` and `user`. `Contact` has a field called `user_id` which (as the name suggest) stores the ID of the user belonging to that contact.

The `user` record is created by a before insert trigger on `contact`. This works great, however I got stuck with trying to update the `user_id` field of the contact. I tried to do it this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.user_id = INSERT INTO user(name)
        VALUES (NEW.name)
        RETURNING id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I link the newly created record to the source of the trigger?

Comment: ... *but it doesn't work*. The error message is ...? PostgreSQL version?

Comment: The problem is that the syntax is just plain wrong, I only posted it to illustrate my intention. I'll try to make that clearer next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `INTO` clause, which is PL/pgSQL specific and unrelated to `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO user(name)
VALUES (NEW.name)
RETURNING id
INTO STRICT NEW.user_id;
```

`INTO STRICT` causes it to raise an error if not exactly one result is inserted.